# How to split on all instances of a word, excluding that word is a substring in quotes?

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex expression to use in Javas Pattern.split() method: I need to appropriately parse the occurrences of word in this string:

--Start--

I want to split on this banana but not 'banana' and i do want to split on this banana but not  'anybananain a substring and\or any banana between each set of literal quotes'

--End--

My first attempt was to try this:

Which splits if the word is surrounded by a space and a boundary, but that also grabs any word with a character on either side, and does not trap between quotes or a larger group of words between a set of quotes.

```
\bbanana\b
```

The other thought i had was something like this:

```
['].\*[^(?:banana)].\*[']|banana
```

which would grab the any string with a banana between quotes or any banana, and only split on the group that matches the second group and not the non-capturing group, but non-capturing groups will still have regex operations performed on them. So it seems that .split with this would not accomplish that either.

There are 5 occurences of banana in the above string, and I only want to split on the first and the third banana in the above string. Is this possible? I need to eliminate splitting on any banana that is encapsulated by '' but could have any number of characters in between those literal quotes

So the output expected would be:

I want to split on this.

But not 'banana' and I do want to split on this.

But not 'anybananain a substring and\or any banana between each set of literal quotes'.

Comment: Split on `(?<!\S)banana(?!\S)`

Comment: @Thefourthbird That works for all except the last `banana` inside the quotes.

Comment: Thank you and that is close, but I do not think that will ignore 'some stuff banana more stuff'' if the banana is between those quotes but separated by spaces

Comment: This is not a good idea to do it with a Java regex. `banana|((?:'[^']*'|(?!banana).)+)` [will work to some extent](https://regex101.com/r/ogHsPq/1) (get `matcher.group(1)` values when a match is found), but it is not efficient. A  simple parsing code would do better.